A Different approach to smallest distance between two points.
So, I was trying to prove the fact that the smallest distance between two points in any dimensions had to be a straight line.
I setup a system to prove it using basic calculus, where I considered $y = f(x)$ to be the trajectory connecting any two points $a_1$ and $a_2$. I took the straight line distance between the two points to be $x$ and made sure that $f(0)_{a_1}=f(x)_{a_2}$ 
I took $S$ to be the line distance of the taken trajectory between $a_1$ and $a_2$
$$S=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+f'(z)^2}dz$$
Differentiating w.r.t $x$ (the variable $x$ in the upper limit) and equating to zero to find the critical point:
$$\frac{dS}{dx}=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}=0 $$
Finding for $f'(x)$, we get:
$$y'=\pm\sqrt{-1}$$
or,
$$y = \pm{ix}+C$$
I felt like an idiot after getting this result, I was expecting to see $y=0$ as my answer but instead I got a complex trajectory as my critical point.
If I now substitute $f'(x) = i$ to find $S$, I get:
$$S=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+i^2}dx=0$$
I think this complex trajectory is somehow related to transformations of plane in such a way that $a_1$ and $a_2$ coincide.
I need help understanding what the result actually signifies.

Hi and welcome to MSE! What's your question? Please edit your post to clarify what it is you actually want to ask.

I want clarification for the result obtained. I also want to ensure whether there are any blunders or not.

I've taken that into consideration, you're welcome!

You might be interested in variational calculus.

Extrema for $f$ can occur (1) where $f'=0$, (2) where $f'$ doesn't exist, or (3) at the endpoints of the domain interval of $f$. There may not be any  point $x$ where $f'(x)=0$. For any differentiable $f$ that is a real-valued function of a real variable, there are no points $x$ where $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}=0$.

It does not help to differentiate with respect to $x$ here. It sounds like you are making the entire trajectory the decision variables, in which case you would need to optimize over all $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ (for all relevant $z$) that start at point $0$ and end at point $x$. So $x$ is actually fixed here .

You can optimize over piecewise linear trajectories more easily.  If $0$ is the starting vector and $x$ is the ending vector, and there are $n$ piecewise linear segments, consider $x-0=\sum_{i=1}^nz_i$ and use the triangle inequality $$||x-0||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||z_i||$$

The aim here is not to somehow manipulate the results to get the desired outcome, but to revolve around the idea of why is $y'=i$ a critical point. I have not specifically mentioned $f(x)$ to be a real-valued function. I just had come across the fact that complex numbers are related to transformation operations, so maybe they just signify the rotation of the euclidean plane itself.

If you want to extend this result to any dimension you ought to work with $|\dot{\boldsymbol x}|$ instead of $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ as $\mathrm d\ell=|\dot{\boldsymbol x}|\,\mathrm dt$, where $\boldsymbol x(t)=(x_1(t),\,...,\,x_n(t))$ would parametrize an arbitrary curve. This way, the arc length integral in $n$ dimensions would be
$$\ell=\int_{t(\boldsymbol a_1)}^{t(\boldsymbol a_2)}|\dot{\boldsymbol x}|\,\mathrm dt=\int_{t(\boldsymbol a_1)}^{t(\boldsymbol a_2)}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\dot x_i^2}\,\mathrm dt$$
If we want to minimize the functional $\ell[\boldsymbol x]$ we may want to compute its first variation, $\delta\ell[\boldsymbol x]$, and set it equal to $0$ or rather just use the Euler-Lagrange equations for each component of $\boldsymbol x$. If you notice, the integrand or Lagrangian, $\mathcal L\equiv\sqrt{\dot x_1^2+...+\dot x_n^2}$ is symmetric if we exchange any of these components. This in turn means all its partial derivatives wrt $\dot x_i$ are equal and since the Lagrangian does not depend on $x_i$ it means the differential equations we get from the E-L equations are the same for all components:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial x_i}-\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial\dot x_i}=0&\implies \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial\dot x_i}=0\\
&\implies \dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial\dot x_i}=\dfrac{\dot x_i}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\dot x_i^2}}=\text{constant}_i,\enspace i=\{1,\,...,\, n\}
\end{aligned}$$
If you divide two equations from any of the $n$ you obtain
$$\dot x_i=A\dot x_j\implies x_i=Ax_j+B,\enspace \forall i\,|\, i\neq j$$
If you do this reapeatedly with one equation and the $n-1$ rest you can express $n-1$ components in terms of some other $x_i$. Basically, parametrizing $x_i$,
$$\boldsymbol x=(A_1x_i+B_1,\,...,\,x_i,\,...,\,A_nx_i+B_n)=\mathbf A\,x_i+\mathbf B$$
which is just a line in $n$ dimensions with direction $\mathbf A$ and "origin" $\mathbf B$.
